# Display PROJECT dependencies

Tags: gradle

Is there a way in Gradle to show me all **PROJECT** dependencies (not artifact deps)

just like this

```
//projectname: :testing-device
dependencies {
    compile project(":web-service-client")
    compile project(":persistency")
}
```

so that

```
:testing-device
+-- :web-service-client
+-- :persistency
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dependencies` task displays both project dependencies and external dependencies. There is no task that displays project dependencies only, but you could write your own.